# Are UX Designers transitioning to be Product Designers though by definition both mean different?

Tags: ux-field, product-design, lean-ux, product-management

I am seeing a steep rise in the way UX Designers are getting the type of tasks under their umbrella. For example, involvement in cost leadership & competitive advantage related discussions with product management team.

It is my observation only, getting overview from community over this topic. Requesting references or perspectives on such transformations.

Comment: In agile lots of people can wear lots of hats, especially in smaller companies. Especially lean agile. So seeing a UX designer also doing Prod Design isn't new. For us we have UI and Graphic designers as our Prod Designers, but POs do the research. Still, expect this to continue rising especially with smaller companies

Comment: In my opinion, yes. But I don't know if there are real studies

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're observing a real trend in the tech industry. The lines between the roles of UX Designers and Product Designers are indeed blurring.

While traditionally UX Designers focused mainly on user research, wireframing, prototyping, and usability testing, their role is evolving. More and more companies are recognizing the value of integrating user experience principles into every stage of the product development process, leading to UX Designers taking on a more holistic approach which is essentially the core of a Product Designer's role.

Product Designers typically oversee the entire product development process from ideation to launch. This involves not just design but also understanding business goals, strategy, and technical constraints, as well as working closely with stakeholders like the product management team, marketing, and engineering.